# How to get occurrence count of a row sorted by date

Tags: mysql, sql

[sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e9d25)

I've a schedule table with following columns.

id
film_id
theatre_id
datetime

Same film can have multiple occurrences like below:

```
id  film_id  theatre_id  datetime
-   -------  ----------  ------
1   1        1           2018-12-07 10:00
2   1        2           2018-12-13 16:00
3   2        3           2018-12-08 10:00
4   1        1           2018-12-08 19:00
```

I would like to have two news column when selecting with the occurrence count and total number of shows grouped by film_id and sorted by film_id,datetime like below:

```
id  film_id  theatre_id  datetime           rank  count
-   -------  ----------  ------             ----  -----
1   1        1           2018-12-07 10:00   1     3 
4   1        1           2018-12-08 19:00   2     3
2   1        2           2018-12-13 16:00   3     3
3   2        3           2018-12-08 10:00   1     1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is rank and count?

Comment: rank - occurrence count, the rank of the row for the same film_id. Count-total number of times a film_id is in the table.

Comment: Why does film_id = 2 have count = 3?

Comment: sorry, by mistake. updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you have window functions:

```
select s.*,
       row_number() over (partition by film_id order by datetime) as rank,
       count(*) over (partition by film_id) as count
from ff_schedule s;
```

In earlier versions, this may be simplest using correlated subqueries:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*)
        from ff_schedule s2
        where s2.film_id = s.film_id and
              s2.datetime < s.datetime
       ) as rank,
       (select count(*)
        from ff_schedule s2
        where s2.film_id = s.film_id 
       ) as cnt
from ff_schedule s;
```

For performance, you want an index on `ff_schedule(film_id, datetime)`.